How to watermark a high-resolution PDF in swift?
I want to watermark the bottom of the first page of a pdf with some text in swift. I have tried using UIGraphicsImageRenderer but that makes the first page blurry. Can I increase the resolution on this or should I use a different method? I am doing it for printing now but in the future I will also use it for the pdf I show on screen.
This is what I have tried.
func watermarkDocument(_ pdfdocument: PDFDocument?) -> PDFDocument? {
    if let document = pdfdocument {
        
        let page = document.page(at: 0)!
        let bounds = page.bounds(for: .cropBox)
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default())
        
        let image = renderer.image { (context) in
            context.cgContext.saveGState()
            
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: bounds.height)
            context.cgContext.concatenate(CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1, y: -1))
            page.draw(with: .cropBox, to: context.cgContext)
            
            context.cgContext.restoreGState()
            
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: (bounds.size.width / 2) - 70, y: bounds.size.height - 20)
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: UIFont(name: "RobotoSlab-Light", size: 8)!,
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            
            let text = "1 copy printed from mywebsite.org"
            text.draw(with: bounds, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: NSStringDrawingContext())
        }
        
        let newPage = PDFPage(image: image)!
        
        for annotation in page.annotations {
            newPage.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
        
        document.insert(newPage, at: 0)
        document.removePage(at: 1)
        
        return document
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

I don't understand UIKit stuff that well so please explain your code. The app is written in SwiftUI.
